# text line breaks in markup between elements

Tags: html, text, newline

I have a bug that results from actual line-breaks in my html markup. I'm trying to find documentation that supports what I'm seeing. This does not have to do with `<br>` or CSS, but instead the newlines within the actual markup. Basically, this:

```
<h4 class="condensed-title-wrap">
  <span class="condensed-title">Here is the title text</span>&nbsp;<i class="icon-icon-navigation-mobile-arrow-right"></i>
</h4>
```

Renders differently than this:

```
<h4 class="condensed-title-wrap">
  <span class="condensed-title">Here is the title text</span>
  &nbsp;
  <i class="icon-icon-navigation-mobile-arrow-right"></i>
</h4>
```

What I'm asking for is language and maybe some documentation that this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The invisible carriage returns and line feeds that occur at the end of the lines count as whitespace (different from non-breaking whitespace such as `&nbsp;`). HTML requires that certain sequences of whitespace are condensed into a single space character. In your second example, the text breaks on the section just before `&nbsp;` which include the previous line break and leading spaces.

This is mentioned in several places in the spec, [one of which](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#strip-and-collapse-whitespace) is quoted here:

> When a user agent is to strip and collapse whitespace in a string, it
>   must replace any sequence of one or more consecutive space characters
>   in that string with a single U+0020 SPACE character, and then strip
>   leading and trailing whitespace from that string.

This issue is often seen when trying to get a pair of `inline-block` formatted elements to place side-to-side, instead ending up with a (often 4 pixel) gap between the elements.

This code produces such a gap:

```
<div>
  <span>left block</span>
  <span>right block</span>
</div>
```

While this code does not:

```
<div>
  <span>left block</span><span>
  right block</span>
</div>
```

The reason for the gap is the whitespace between the end of one `span` and the beginning of the next. The solution moves the whitespace from between the `span` elements to the beginning of a string where it is ignored rather than condensed.